# Does 'family sharing' require that members use same apple ID for both iTunes and iCloud?

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-id, family-sharing

Each member of our family has two unique Apple ID's, one for use with iTunes and another for iCloud (e.g. 4 members, 8 Apple ID's). On the [family sharing](http://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/) page it says "Family Sharing requires a personal Apple ID signed in to iCloud and iTunes". We are hoping to achieve not only the shared apps functionality of 'family sharing' but also the shared calendar, photos and Apple music subscription.

Does this mean that each of us has to use the Apple ID's for our personal iCloud accounts to signin to itunes if we want to use 'family sharing'? i.e. we have to use the same Apple ID for iTunes and iCloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Family Sharing, you need to have the same Apple ID on both iCloud and iTunes.  It looks to me like you'll need to decide which Apple ID's your family wants to use and stick with that.

On a side note, I don't understand why you'd want to have seperate ID's for each service.  I'm sure you have a good reason but I would strongly recommend using only 1 ID for everything Apple.

Comment: Some of us are stuck with separate accounts, due to having an iTunes account long before iCloud existed.

Comment: I did, too, but I stopped using the old account and moved to just 1 account.  I can still access items from my old ID but at some point it's just easier to stop using it and settle on just one.

Comment: All my purchases are on the iTunes account, every app & Mac since 2005. I joined MobileMe in 2009, but already had too much at stake to leave it behind. One day...one day, they will allow us to merge accounts :/